# Visual Studio Code 2019 python pandas maximum records?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code

I'm working with Visual Studio Code 2019 using Python to fetch records from yfinance, here is the code:

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
df_ticker1 = ticker.history(start='1996-01-01', end='2021-01-01')
    
file_name3 = "Temp-df_ticker.csv"
    df_ticker1.to_csv(file_name3)
```

When open the csv file, it only contain the data start from "6/29/2010" only 2647 records, but if I run the same in Google Colab, the start date is correct (1996-01-01).
Is there any record limitation in Visual Studio Code 2019 or Pandas?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this in the latest Insiders' build of VS Code. Could you try updating your install, and rerunning the command?